# Login with FB Button

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am using CS Cart ecommerce system and I have gone through all the tutorials on facebook and various other sites to integrate facebook to my site. Meaning, I have standard user registration on my site. However, I am looking to implement to Login with facebook button where a facebook user will be able to login using his facebook credentials. I was also asked to refer to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

I am not a programmer to understand this. If somebody can help, it will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

for that you need to create [app in the facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and than you need the appkey and secrete

> [image]

and set the url make sure that the site url is on the same page where you have the login button and there can not be login button on multiple place with the same app

[image]

and the following script

```
<?php

define('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR APP ID');

//uses the PHP SDK.  Download from https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
  'secret' => 'YOUR APP SECRET',
));

$userId = $facebook->getUser();

?>

<html>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <?php if ($userId) { 
      $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' . $userId); ?>
      Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>


        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
              channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
          };
          // Load the SDK Asynchronously
          (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
           }(document));
        </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

you can see full documentation and tutorial  at [Facebook for Websites](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)